# Setting a bunch of compile options in CMake in a non-repetitive way

Tags: cmake

I work on a project where there are a bunch of configuration options. At the moment the code expects them to be passed on the command line via `-D`. They are hard-coded in the old build script, I want to expose them via CMake.

For the boolean options I came up with this construction:

```
option(FOO1 "" ON)
option(FOO2 "" ON)
option(FOO3 "" OFF)

target_compile_definitions(
        mylib
        PRIVATE
        $<$<BOOL:${FOO1}>:FOO1>
        $<$<BOOL:${FOO2}>:FOO2>
        $<$<BOOL:${FOO3}>:FOO3>
)
```

It seems to work, but I need to write `FOO1` three times, and it looks rather ugly. In the code one can then use `#ifdef FOO1` to check that.

For the valued options I have the following:

```
set(BAR1 default_value CACHE STRING "")
set(BAR2 default_value CACHE STRING "")

target_compile_definitions(
        mylib
        PRIVATE
        BAR1=${BAR1}
        BAR2=${BAR2}
)
```

Again I need to write `BAR1` three times. At least in the code I can just use the definitions and don't have to explicitly define them again.

I am open to use a `config.h.in` for this. But there I would have to write `FOO1 = "@FOO1@"` or `FOO1 = "${FOO1}"`, again having to state the option two more times.

Is there some more clever way to define a bunch of compile definitions?

Comment: "but I need to write `FOO1` three times" - Do you mean "write `FOO1` **two** times"? You have three lines like `$<$<BOOL:${FOO1}>:FOO1>` but the name of the option differs in each line. If you want to not repeat `$<$<BOOL:${option}>:option>` multiple times for different `option` name, then you may create a function/macro for that option and call just call this function 3 times. Or iterate (`foreach`) calls to this function for every option name. Or perform iteration over option names inside the function... Too many approaches. Just *imagine* a way, how do you intend to use a function/macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a loop for this purpose:

```
foreach(_VAR IN ITEMS
    FOO1
    FOO2
    FOO3
    )

    if(${_VAR})
        target_compile_definitions(mylib PRIVATE "${_VAR}")
    endif()
endforeach()

foreach(_VAR IN ITEMS
    BAR1
    BAR2
    BAR3
    )

    target_compile_definitions(mylib PRIVATE "${_VAR}=${${_VAR}}")
endforeach()
```

Unfortunately this is actually longer than your code, but it does avoid the repetition. For more options this would be more worthwhile.

Comment: Given the number of variables that I have, this option is still shorter. And most importantly easier to maintain. Thanks a lot!